# How many socket will open while listening firestore by DocumentReference

Tags: c#, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in Cloud Firestore. When I read the documentation I saw the code below:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("cities").Document("SF");
FirestoreChangeListener listener = docRef.Listen(snapshot =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Callback received document snapshot.");
    Console.WriteLine("Document exists? {0}", snapshot.Exists);
    if (snapshot.Exists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Document data for {0} document:", snapshot.Id);
        Dictionary<string, object> city = snapshot.ToDictionary();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
});
```

Actually I know how to listen by filtered query and listen all 300 records from a query snapshot, however even if there is only one document update, query reads all records and it increases read count (so does cost) dramatically.

What if I have 300 documents and I want to listen them all for real time updates by document reference snapshot.
**Will there be 300 separated sockets or one singleton socket for listening them all. Are C# driver and Flutter driver behavior same ?**

Implementation will be like this;

```
foreach (var docRef in docRefList) //300 records
{
    FirestoreChangeListener listener = docRef.Listen(snapshot =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callback received document snapshot.");
        Console.WriteLine("Document exists? {0}", snapshot.Exists);
        if (snapshot.Exists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Document data for {0} document:", snapshot.Id);
            Dictionary<string, object> city = snapshot.ToDictionary();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you interact with Firebase Realtime Database, a **single** socket connection between your application and Firebase servers is opened. From that moment on, all traffic between the application and the database goes over **that same** socket. So it doesn't matter how many times you create an instance of the Realtime Database, it will always be a single connection.

On the other hand, according to @Frank van Puffelen's comment, when you interact with a Cloud Firestore database, the client connects to Firestore using HTTP/2 connections, not web sockets. Both HTTP/2 and web sockets send multiple requests over a single connection.

If there are no active listeners for a period of time, the Cloud Firestore client will automatically close the connection but it will re-open the connection when you attach a listener or perform a read/write operation again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I need.

Comment: *firebaser here* What you're descriving is how Realtime Database clients connect to their servers. Firestore clients use HTTP/2 connections, not web sockets. While commonly HTTP/2 may also send multiple requests over a single connection, the details are quite different.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Just updated my answer according to your comment. Thank you, puf!