# Which protocol does Firebase use to communicate with mobile app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How does Firebase communicate with my Android app? Does it use HTTP, HTTPS, Websocket or which protocol? I've declared `firestore` dependency and I call my backend let's say via `.subscribe()` or `.get()` methods. Thank you.

Comment: You can just add a proxy/sniffer and check by yourself.

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590579/how-many-socket-will-open-while-listening-firestore-by-documentreference) might help.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you for response. What kind of `sockets` do Firebase use under the hood? Is it `websockets`? Are they secure? Is there an official documentation for that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Firestore clients use HTTP/2 connections, **not** web sockets. Even if you send multiple requests, all of them are sent over a single connection.

On the other hand, the Realtime Database clients will always open a single socket connection between the application and Firebase servers.

More info in the article below:

- [HTTP/2 comes to Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/http2-comes-to-firebase-hosting.html)